# Java inheritance and recursion

Tags: java, inheritance, recursion

I have a superclass and a subclass as follows:

```
class Tree{
 ..
 public void add(..){
 //makes a call to protected function add(..) 
 }//for client to use.
 protected TreeNode add(..){}//recursive function which calls itslef
}

class Stree extends Tree{
 //overrides the recursive add function from class Tree
 protected TreeNode add(..){
   ..
   super.add();//calls the non-recursive add function in superclass.
 }
}
```

The problem here is that when I call `super.add()` from the new add function in the subclass, it goes to `Tree.add()`. Inside `Tree.add()`. there is a call to `add()`, which calls the recursive add function in the subclass instead of super, i.e. `Stree.add()`, instead of `Tree.add()` which results in an infinite loop. Do you guys see where the problem is?

This is a homework assignment hence I cannot change the name of the recursive function. I am explicitly required to add functionality to the recursive add function, without rewriting any existing code, which basically means I will have to make a call to the original `add()` function.

edit: Code for the Tree.add()//recursive. Note that I cannot modify this code to gain the functionality I seek.

```
protected StreeNode add(StreeNode node, String value) {
        if (node == null) {
            node = new StreeNode(value);
            numElements++;
        } else if (node.data.compareTo(value) == 0) {
            // do nothing, String was already in Set
        } else if (node.data.compareTo(value) > 0) {
            node.left = add(node.left, value);      // x = change(x)
        } else {
            node.right = add(node.right, value);    // x = change(x)
        }

        return node;
    }
```

edit: Now that I see that this is the expected behaviour, how do I go about achieving the following:

1. Add the value using the original recursive `add()`
2. Implement extra functionality

Comment: change the name of your protected method

Comment: Why are you overriding the recursive call?

Comment: There's no problem ... that's exactly what it is supposed to do. ;)

Comment: unfortunately I cannot do that. The method name needs to remain the same.

Comment: That's the expected behavior.. why can't you change the method name?

Comment: Can you post the implementation of add in Tree? If you have an infinite loop it is in there, irregardless of your subclass

Comment: I have edited my post. Oh I see this is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the parameters I assume `void add(...)` is the method to add something into the tree, whereas the protected recursive method looks for the node to add to and then performs the add.

I further assume the public non-recursive method passes the tree's root to the recursive method as a start parameter while the recursive method either passes the left or right child until you hit a leaf. Calling the non-recursive method might thus in starting at the root again and again.

Thus I'd say that the recursive and inherited method should not call the non-recursive version but should call itself again.

Comment: Hey although your answer is not exactly the solution, it made me think that I could be making a mistake somewhere with the method calls and I guess I was. Thanks ^__^

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This is random, may not make much sense.

In your comments, it says your Tree.add is recursive, and that STree.add is recursive:

Create protected method Tree.addCommon(..), which does not recurse, just does the stuff that needs to be done.

Tree.add(..) calls addCommon(..), and then this.add(..) to recurse.

STree.add(..) does it's extra stuff, calls super.addCommon(..) for the common stuff, and then this.add(..) to recurse.

I know. should have written pseudo-code. Lazy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my post. I cannot modify the Tree class in anyway. I have to do it using the add function which must override the original recursive add, although I can use helper methods in Stree class. Sorry if question wasnt clear

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the case if you can't modify the class, but I think the best solution is to create another method called addHelper(...) that will be responsible for the recursion, then you call this helper inside the add(...) method.