# Inheritance and recursion

Tags: java, inheritance, recursion

Suppose we have the following classes:

```
class A {

    void recursive(int i) {
        System.out.println("A.recursive(" + i + ")");
        if (i > 0) {
            recursive(i - 1);
        }
    }

}

class B extends A {

    void recursive(int i) {
        System.out.println("B.recursive(" + i + ")");
        super.recursive(i + 1);
    }

}
```

Now lets call `recursive` in class A:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.recursive(10);
    }

}
```

The output is, as expected counting down from 10.

```
A.recursive(10)
A.recursive(9)
A.recursive(8)
A.recursive(7)
A.recursive(6)
A.recursive(5)
A.recursive(4)
A.recursive(3)
A.recursive(2)
A.recursive(1)
A.recursive(0)
```

Let's get to the the confusing part. Now we call `recursive` in class B.

**Expected**:

```
B.recursive(10)
A.recursive(11)
A.recursive(10)
A.recursive(9)
A.recursive(8)
A.recursive(7)
A.recursive(6)
A.recursive(5)
A.recursive(4)
A.recursive(3)
A.recursive(2)
A.recursive(1)
A.recursive(0)
```

**Actual**:

```
B.recursive(10)
A.recursive(11)
B.recursive(10)
A.recursive(11)
B.recursive(10)
A.recursive(11)
B.recursive(10)
..infinite loop...
```

How does this happen? I know this is a devised example, but it makes me wonder.

Older question with a [concrete use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357029/java-inheritance-and-recursion).

Comment: The keyword you need is static and dynamic types! you should search for that and read a bit about it.

Comment: You are running afool of Java's virtual-by-default. [How is defining that a method can be overridden a stronger commitment than defining that a method can be called?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/304270/how-is-defining-that-a-method-can-be-overridden-a-stronger-commitment-than-defin)

Comment: To get your desired results extract the recursive method to a new private method.

Comment: @Onots I think making the recursive methods static would be cleaner.

Comment: It's simple if you notice that the recursive call in `A` is actually *dynamically dispatched* to the the `recursive` method of the current object. If you are working with an `A` object, the call takes you to `A.recursive()`, and with a `B` object, to `B.recursive()`. But `B.recursive()` always calls `A.recursive()`. So, if you start a `B` object, it switches back and forth.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This is expected. This is what happens for an instance of `B`.

```
class A {

    void recursive(int i) { // <-- 3. this gets called
        System.out.println("A.recursive(" + i + ")");
        if (i > 0) {
            recursive(i - 1); // <-- 4. this calls the overriden "recursive" method in class B, going back to 1.
        }
    }

}

class B extends A {

    void recursive(int i) { // <-- 1. this gets called
        System.out.println("B.recursive(" + i + ")");
        super.recursive(i + 1); // <-- 2. this calls the "recursive" method of the parent class
    }

}
```

As such, the calls are alternating between `A` and `B`.

This doesn't happen in the case of an instance of `A` because the overriden method won't be called.

Answer (score 29):

Because `recursive(i - 1);` in `A` refers to `this.recursive(i - 1);` which is `B#recursive` in second case. So, `super` and `this` will be called in *recursive* function *alternatively*.

```
void recursive(int i) {
    System.out.println("B.recursive(" + i + ")");
    super.recursive(i + 1);//Method of A will be called
}
```

in `A`

```
void recursive(int i) {
    System.out.println("A.recursive(" + i + ")");
    if (i > 0) {
        this.recursive(i - 1);// call B#recursive
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

The other answers have all explained the essential point, that once an instance method is overridden it stays overridden and there's no getting it back except through `super`. `B.recursive()` invokes `A.recursive()`. `A.recursive()` then invokes `recursive()`, which resolves to the override in `B`. And we ping pong back and forth until the end of the universe or a `StackOverflowError`, whichever comes first.

It would be nice if one could write `this.recursive(i-1)` in `A` to get its own implementation, but that would probably break things and have other unfortunate consequences, so `this.recursive(i-1)` in `A` invokes `B.recursive()` and so forth.

There is a way to get the expected behavior, but it requires foresight. In other words, you must know in advance that you want a `super.recursive()` in a subtype of `A` to get trapped, so to speak, in the `A` implementation. It is done like so:

```
class A {

    void recursive(int i) {
        doRecursive(i);
    }

    private void doRecursive(int i) {
        System.out.println("A.recursive(" + i + ")");
        if (i > 0) {
            doRecursive(i - 1);
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {

    void recursive(int i) {
        System.out.println("B.recursive(" + i + ")");
        super.recursive(i + 1);
    }
}
```

Since `A.recursive()` invokes `doRecursive()` and `doRecursive()` can never be overridden, `A` is assured that it is calling its own logic.

Comment: I wonder, why calling `doRecursive()` inside `recursive()` from the object `B` works. As TAsk wrote in his answer a function call works like `this.doRecursive()` and the Object `B` (`this`) has no method `doRecursive()` because it is in class `A` defined as `private` and not `protected` and will therefore be not inherited, right?

Comment: Object `B` can't call `doRecursive()` at all. `doRecursive()` is `private`, yes. But when `B` calls `super.recursive()`, that invokes the implementation of `recursive()` in `A`, which has access to `doRecursive()`.

Comment: This is exactly the approach Bloch recommends in Effective Java if you absolutely must allow inheritance.  Item 17: "If you feel you must allow inheritance from [a concrete class that doesn't implement a standard interface], one reasonable approach is to ensure that the class never invokes any of its overridable methods and to document the fact."

Answer (score 16):

`super.recursive(i + 1);` in class `B` calls the super class's method explicitly, so `recursive` of `A` is called once.

Then, `recursive(i - 1);` in class A would call the `recursive` method in class `B` which overrides `recursive` of class `A`, since it is executed on an instance of class `B`.

Then `B`'s `recursive` would call `A`'s `recursive` explicitly, and so on.

Answer (score 16):

That actually cannot go any other way.

When you call `B.recursive(10);`, then it prints `B.recursive(10)` then calls the implementation of this method in `A` with `i+1`.

So you call `A.recursive(11)`, which prints `A.recursive(11)` which calls the `recursive(i-1);` method on the current instance which is `B` with input parameter `i-1`, so it calls `B.recursive(10)`, which then calls the super implementation with `i+1` which is `11`, which then recursively calls the current instance recursive with `i-1` which is `10`, and you'll get the loop that you see here.

This is all because if you call the method of the instance in the superclass, you'll still call the implementation of the instance on which you're calling it.

Imagine this,

```
 public abstract class Animal {

     public Animal() {
         makeSound();
     }

     public abstract void makeSound();         
 }

 public class Dog extends Animal {
     public Dog() {
         super(); //implicitly called
     }

     @Override
     public void makeSound() {
         System.out.println("BARK");
     }
 }

 public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Dog dog = new Dog();
     }
 }
```

You'll get "BARK" instead of a compilation error such as "the abstract method cannot be called on this instance" or a runtime error `AbstractMethodError` or even `pure virtual method call` or something like that. So this is all to support [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Answer (score 14):

When a `B` instance's `recursive` method calls the `super`class implementation, the instance being acted on is still of `B`. Therefore when the super class's implementation calls `recursive` without further qualification, *that's the subclass implementation*. The result is the never-ending loop you're seeing.